# go back to main view

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, program-entry-point

Hello 
I have a main view and I add another view with add subview. Then I add and 3rd view with add subview. Now I want to go back on the main view. How will I do that?
(I cant use addsubview:view or _view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactely sure what you mean by "going back" to the mainview, but you can send messages to your superview via delegation. Just set a delegate in your subview and set it to self upon adding it as a subview and releasing it.

If by "going back" you mean removing all subviews, then just call -removeFromSuperview from every subview and you should be fine :)

Comment: I have mainview->secondview->thirdview(using addsubview) and from thirdview I want to go on the mainview. I tried addsubview:_view and I get error. the [thirdview removefromsuperview] is doing nothing

Comment: Check out the documentation for UIView: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeFromSuperview) If you post your code I might be able to help you :)